# Non Smooth K3 surface?

Tags: k3-surfaces, smoothness, geometric-structures

Hi,

My question is related to Algebraic Surfaces. I have seen that we always consider K3 surfaces which are smooth, but I wonder how can we define a non-smooth K3 surface.

The problem I see is on the canonical bundle.   So if we suppose $X$ is an algebraic surface ofer a field $K$ and suppose we hace that the singular divisor is normal crossing. Then we have logarithmic differentials. So I wonder if the definition of non-smooth K3 surface is the one that I am imagine, that is:  $X$ is a $K3$ surface if $H^1(X, \mathfrak O_X)=0$ and $\Omega^2_X(log)$ is trivial...

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An algebraic (possibly singular) $K3$ surface is a normal algebraic surface whose minimal resolution is a smooth $K3$ surface. You can obtain these for example by blowing down $(-2)$-curves on a smooth algebraic $K3$. As long as you only do that you can even restrict the kind of singularities you allow. For example blowing down a  $(-2)$-curve (and certain configurations) will lead to Du Val (=rational Gorenstein=rational double points) singularities.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you have a reference for this? I would like also to know if people work with logarithmic geometry on singular K3 surfaces.  Thanks a lot. 

Comment: I don't know a good reference. I learnt this definition from my advisor when I was a graduate student. As a result I put it in a paper that was based on my thesis and no one has complained yet...


Comment: ok, Thanks. I think that your answer also is related with what I was thinking. Thanks a lot! 


Comment: This is quite late, but here's a reference for anywhere in the future: Definition 3.2 in Yuya Matsumoto. $\mu_p$- and $\alpha_p$-actions on K3 surfaces in characteristic $p$. J. Algebraic Geom., 32(2):271–322,
2023

Comment: arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03466